# How to press "ALT+T" in Selenium webdriver with java. I want to switch tabs by pressing it

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have used below code, but it throws an error saying "Cannot focus on element". Please help.

```
String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.ALT,"T");
driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(selectAll);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to switch tabs would be to use switchTo(), if you know the new window name:

```
driver.switchTo().window(WINDOW_NAME);
```

Otherwise get a list of the open windows and switch using that:

```
List<String> openTabs = driver.getWindowHandles();

    for(String tab in openTabs) {
     driver.switchTo().window(openTabs.get(tab);
    }
```

So you can iterate over the open windows until you find the one you need.

Comment: Can anybody let me know the Correct Syntax ??  i am very new to Selenium.the above code is not working. I am using Chrome Driver.

Answer (score 1):

You can send ShortcutKeys like `Alt + Tab` to driver without using element by using Actions.

```
public static void sendShortCut(WebDriver driver) {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
     action.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "T")).build().perform();
}
```

However your goal was to switch to the window/tab.In Selenium both window and tab are same.

I've provided you two solutions which is self explanatory from the name of the functions

```
public static void switchToWindowByTitle(WebDriver driver, String title) {
    Set<String> Handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String handle : Handles) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        String drivertitle = driver.getTitle().trim();
        if (drivertitle.equals(title)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Index is 0 based
public static void switchToWindowByIndex(WebDriver driver, int index) {
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    if (handles.size() > index) {
        String handle = handles.toArray()[index].toString();
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting an error void is an invalid type for the variable switchToWindowByIndex

Comment: @SrikrishnaNadagouda You have to put the function outside the main() and how are you calling the function?Can you post your code

Answer (score 0):

You can open another tab using:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
```

and switch to tabs by using:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```