# how to assert store value to with other?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I had a Webform in which there is link , on click it open another new window where i need to assert Email ID value present in that.

Webdriver Script :

```
driver.get("http://domain.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"submit\"]")).click();
    driver.get("http://domain.com/AffiliateAdmin/Home");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(em);//em store email id value , which is random generated for new account creation.
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='submit']")).click();
    assertEquals(em, driver.findElement(By.xpath("/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[11]/x:td[2]/x:a")).getText());
    System.out.println("Test Case Passed");
```

Please Help Me out for Same

A script is most valuable for me

Thanks

Comment: What you want to do with popup?Are you using Java selenium-webdriver?

Comment: @Youth India:  Can you show what have you  tried?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162378/how-to-press-altt-in-selenium-webdriver-with-java-i-want-to-switch-tabs-by-p/31167860#31167860)

Answer (score 1):

```
        String mainwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();        

        // click on the Update btn (use XPATH or CssSelector)
        driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("a[onclick^='window.open(\'/AffiliateAdmin/Update-Affiliate?Email']")).click(); //click to brings out the new window

        Set<String> s = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
        Iterator<String> ite = s.iterator(); 
        while(ite.hasNext()) 
        { 
            String popup = ite.next(); 
            if(!popup.equalsIgnoreCase(mainwindow)){ 
                driver.switchTo().window(popup); 
                break;
              }
        }

       // do Assert here
```

Comment: I guess his issue is not with handling pop up. He is trying to store a value which is an output after `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"submit\"]")).click();`. In the next step, he is going to the popup and trying to assert if the value in the popup is same as that of previous.